# Question on eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\hat{n}$ be an arbitrary unit vector and $\Delta$ a diagonal matrix of size $m\times m$ with positive entries (at least one entry is greater than one). I would like to show that the sequence of matrices $(I - \hat{n}\hat{n}^T)\Delta^k(I - \hat{n}\hat{n}^T)$ has the same eigenvectors for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Please note that $I - \hat{n}\hat{n}^T$ is not diagonal.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried for $m=2$ and it is true. Observe that I can change diagonal $\Delta$ with any symmetric positive definite matrix.

Comment: Moreover it is easy to see that $\hat{n}$ will be an eigenvector with eigenvalue zero. But the other eigenvalues and eigenvectors become complicated if one wants to express them in terms of entries of $\Delta$ and $\hat{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all properties are vector (except that at least one entry of $\Delta$ is greater than one, but it's not important as we can achieve it by multiplying $\Delta$ by some number as long as $\Delta$ is non-zero), so we can write it in any basis we want.

Lets use basis with $\hat n = e_1$, then $I - \hat n \hat n^T$ is just projector on last $m - 1$ coordinates. $\Delta$ will be some positive definite matrix in this basis. If there is a counterexample in this formulation, we can transform it to counterexample of original formulation by switching to eigen-basis of $\Delta$.

And it's now quite easy to find counterexample, as eigenvectors when $k = 1$ don't depend on upper row (and left column) of $\Delta$, but with $k > 1$ do depend. For example, $\left(\begin{matrix} 10 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 20 & 12 \\ 0 & 12 & 30\end{matrix}\right)$ works.